# Count of distinct values in a column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table like

```
machine_id      OS
----------      --
1               PC
2               PC
3               MAC
4               UNIX
5               PC
```

How do I return each OS and the number of times it occurs? I can't group by OS because I would just get a distinct list of OS. I want to know how many times each OS occurs in the column

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`, `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Add the expected result as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 select OS, count(*)as TotalForOS
 from table
 group by OS
```

Comment: Thanks that did it! For some reason I thought that formulation would give me a count of 1 for each OS since there was a group clause...

Comment: i think it will be helpful to know the execution order in sql server,:
1. FROM
2. ON
3. OUTER
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. CUBE | ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10. ORDER BY
11. TOP Number specify the actual execution order not the logical order you type for your query